# How to create routing inside a modal window [ ANGULAR 5 ]?

Tags: angular, routes, angular5, angular-routing, nested-routes

I have a requirement where i need to switch between 2 different views back and forth based on certain condition inside a **modal window's body**.

Those 2 views are :

1. List items (Initial view)
2. Add new items

After adding new items i need to switch to the List items view.

**NOTE:** All these views should be displayed inside a modal windows body.

So using ANGULAR 5 routing how can i create new routes / sub routes inside this modal component ?

Comment: add ```<router-outlet>``` tag in your model and all the contents will be load there

Comment: you could pass it as a param to the modal, and figure out which UI to load inside of it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create another router-outlet with a name like this

```
<router-outlet name="modal"></router-outlet>
```

To navigate to it in your ts, use

```
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { modal: 'route' }}])
```

while in your html, use

```
<button md-button  [routerLink]="[{outlets: {'modal': ['route']}}]">Speakers</button>
```

you can also specify it in your routes like

```
{ path: ':id', component: YourComponent, outlet: 'modal' }
```

Comment: Thanks Ekene.
Where exactly do you put the named route?
<router-outlet name="modal"></router-outlet>

Comment: In the modal itself. i.e where you want the content to be rendered