# How to create routing inside a modal window?

Tags: angular, routes, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, angular7

My question is exactly same as this question
[How to create routing inside a modal window [ ANGULAR 5 ]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51746420/how-to-create-routing-inside-a-modal-window-angular-5)

The answer is provided but I am unable to understand the ans.
Can someone give me proper complete answer. Means where to add routing and all other stuff.

My Modal code is:

```
<div class="modal" id="modalEditPersonalSetting">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                    <div class="card navbar navbar-expand-md" id="secondnavbar">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button class="w3-btn" routerLink="/edit">Edit</button>
                            <button class="w3-btn" routerLink="/profile">Change Profile</button>
                        </div>
                     </div>
            </div>
            <!-- I need selected component html should be loaded here depending on selected component -->
            <router-outlet name="modal"></router-outlet>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Need to load routed page below that modal navbar inside The Modal Window Itself

Comment: do you use list of route in `app.module` or in `AppRoutingModule`?

Comment: Yes, I have used it @לבנימלכה

Comment: can you show me you button to click and open modal

Comment: <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditPersonalSetting" style="margin-top:30px" > 
                Open Setting
                </a>